# How to make StarRating widget alignment left side

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make StarRating widget alignment left side?
I tried this code but no effect

Updated with full code

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text((p1 != null ? p1.name : obj1 != null ? obj1.p_name : "")),
  ),
  body: Align(
alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: StarRating(
                    size: 20,
                    rating: 4.5,
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                  ),
  )

                          );
```

Comment: please, add some more code because it depends upon it's parent widget to.

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify the **flutter_rating.dart** file.

Original Build Method:

```
new Material(
  type: MaterialType.transparency,
  child: new Center(
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: new List.generate(
        starCount,
        (index) => buildStar(context, index),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Just Remove the Center Widget and center property of Row Widget.

Like Below.

```
new Material(
  type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: new Row(
      children: new List.generate(
        starCount,
        (index) => buildStar(context, index),
      ),
    ),
);
```

i hope that it works for you.